# How to create target lines in a rowchart in dc.js

Tags: javascript, charts, analytics, dc.js

i'm using a rowchart to show the total of sales by item of a salesman.

Already tried a composite chart unsuccessfully like many posts from the google, but none of the examples uses a rowchart.

[image]

I need to do like the image, creating the red lines to represent the sale value target for each item, but i dont know how, can you guys help me? Thanks!

Actually this is my code to plot the rowchart

```
spenderRowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row-spenders");        

spenderRowChart
    .width(450).height(200)
    .dimension(itemDim)
    .group(totalItemGroup)
    .elasticX(true);
```

Comment: If you're just trying to add a few lines, probably a pretransition/renderlet hook is the easiest way to go. What you are doing is a simpler version of [this example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/bar-extra-line.html). aha... found an exact duplicate

Comment: Can't file this as a duplicate because the answer was not accepted, but please take a look at this question/answer and see if it works for you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125887/draw-extra-line-in-row-line-with-dc-js/49238755#49238755

Comment: @Gordon hey, actually i'm using this example in my current code but if you look the example, the line is not dynamic and cover all the rows, its not what i precisely want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you need a source for the target data, which could be a global map, or a field in your data.

I've created [an example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/row-targets.html) which pulls the data from a global, but it would also take from the data if your group reduction provides a field called `target`.

Then, it adds a new `path` element to each row. Conveniently the rows are already SVG [`g` group elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g), so anything put in there will already be offset to the top left corner of the row rect.

The only coordinate we are missing is the height of the rect, which we can get by reading it from one of the existing bars:

```
    var height = chart.select('g.row rect').attr('height');
```

Then we select the `g`s and use the general update pattern to add a `path.target` to each one if it doesn't have one. We'll make it red, make it visible only if we have data for that row, and start it at X 0 so that it will animate from the left like the row rects do:

```
    var target = chart.selectAll('g.row')
        .selectAll('path.target').data(function(d) { return [d]; });
    target = target.enter().append('path')
        .attr('class', 'target')
        .attr('stroke', 'red')
        .attr('visibility', function(d) {
            return (d.value.target !== undefined || _targets[d.key] !== undefined) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        })
        .attr('d', function(d) {
            return 'M0,0 v' + height;
        }).merge(target);
```

The final `.merge(target)` merges this selection into the main selection.

Now we can now animate all target lines into position:

```
    target.transition().duration(chart.transitionDuration())
        .attr('visibility', function(d) {
            return (d.value.target !== undefined || _targets[d.key] !== undefined) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        })
        .attr('d', function(d) {
            return 'M' + (chart.x()(d.value.target || _targets[d.key] || 0)+0.5) + ',0 v' + height;
        });
```

The example doesn't show it, but this will also allow the targets to move dynamically if they change or the scale changes. Likewise targets may also become visible or invisible if data is added/removed.

Answer (score 2):

thank you, due the long time to have an answer i've developed a solution already, but, really thank you and its so nice beacause its pretty much the same ideia, so i think its nice to share the code here too.

The difference its in my code i use other logic to clear the strokes and use the filter value of some other chart to make it dynamic.

```
    .renderlet(function(chart) {
        dc.events.trigger(function() {
            filter1 = yearRingChart.filters();
            filter2 = spenderRowChart.filters();
        });
    })

    .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        if (aux_path.length > 0){
            for (i = 0; i < aux_path.length; i++){
                aux_path[i].remove();
            }
        };

        aux_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data2));
        aux_data = aux_data.filter(venda => filter1.indexOf(venda.Nome) > -1);

        meta_subgrupo = [];
        aux_data.forEach(function(o) {
            var existing = meta_subgrupo.filter(function(i) { return i.SubGrupo === o.SubGrupo })[0];
            if (!existing)
                meta_subgrupo.push(o);
            else
                existing.Meta += o.Meta;
        });
        
        if (filter1.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; (i < Object.keys(subGrupos).length); i++){                 
                var x_vert = meta_subgrupo[i].Meta;
                var extra_data = [
                    {x: chart.x()(x_vert), y: 0},
                    {x: chart.x()(x_vert), y: chart.effectiveHeight()}
                ];
                var line = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                    .curve(d3.curveLinear);
                var chartBody = chart.select('g');
                var path = chartBody.selectAll('path.extra').data([extra_data]);
                path = path.enter()
                        .append('path')
                        .attr('class', 'oeExtra')
                        .attr('stroke', subGruposColors[i].Color)
                        .attr('id', 'ids')
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,3"))
                    .merge(path)
                path.attr('d', line);
                aux_path.push(path);
            }  
        }
})
```

And that's how it looks

[image]